# How to fade a div out with jQuery and have it stay faded while mouse is over child elements of the original trigger?

Tags: jquery

I have a login form in a div on the homepage of a new site, this form also appears in the dropdown navigation.  I would like to panel in the main content of the page to fade out while:

- the mouse is hovered over the main dropdown link
- also while the mouse is over the dropdown menu prtion [i.e. filling out the dropdown form]

What I have is:

```
$('.login-toggle').hover(function(){
        console.log('hover in');
        $('.splash .login-panel').stop().fadeOut();
    },function(){
        console.log('hover out');
        $(".splash .login-panel").stop().fadeIn();
    });
```

Which does work, however as soon as the mouse leaves the a element, the main content form reappears.

here is the login dropdown.

```
<!-- login -->
<li class="has-submenu" >
     <a href="#" class="login-toggle">Login</a>
     <ul class="submenu menu vertical mega-submenu-login" data-submenu>
          <li>
               <div class="login-panel">
               <!-- login form -->
               </div>
          </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

So this works fine while the user is hovered over the a element above, but how can I keep the '.splash .login-panel' [in the body of the page] hidden while the user has the mouse over the form or ul containing the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

I hope Is this the result you are looking for:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rerdecwk/)

```
var clr;

$('.login-toggle, ul.submenu').hover(function(){

  console.log('hover in');
  $('.splash .login-panel').stop().fadeOut();
  clearTimeout(clr);

},function(){

  clr = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('hover out');
    $(".splash .login-panel").stop().fadeIn();
  }, 500);

});
```

Comment: seems to work fine in your example, but isn't working properly in my menu.  sometimes it will stay hidden, other times it will fade back in.

Comment: looking at the menu, [Foundation 6] a class is added t the parent element when it is open "is-active"  -   there must be some way to attach my fade behaviour to that?

Comment: @SeanKimball I think the best try is to insert the selector of the closest tag/class of your menu (I think "ul.menu", checking foundation menu structure) and grow up the timer (1000 milliseconds), check this: https://jsfiddle.net/rerdecwk/1/ In my example not work the sub menu, but I think is not the point.